# How does Empire Powershell interact with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

The creators of Empire PowerShell state the following:

> "Empire implements the ability to run PowerShell agents without
>   needing powershell.exe"

https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/Empire

Wouldn't running any component of PowerShell require the executable?

Comment: This question also seems a lot like this question -- http://security.stackexchange.com/q/109905/140

Comment: That's true, reading your explanation there again I see the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen of the source, especially the functions starting [here](https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/Empire/blob/master/lib/common/helpers.py#L142) in `helpers.py` it merely wraps the PowerShell executable. There's a lot in there that's sort of haphazard command parsing and construction and output parsing. I would have actually expected it to be a PowerShell host that simply offers a Python API, but from the looks of it, it's a Python API that wraps a few commands, simply shells out to PowerShell, and parses the output as text.

Comment: Thank you Joey, that was also part of my doubt, how Python interacted with PS.